# Objective-c pass two parameters into a bool method

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this NSArray method here:

```
-(NSArray*)User:(NSString *)user andPassWordExists:(NSString *)password
```

but I do not need to return an array anymore, just a yes or no, how would I change this method into a BOOL method ?

```
-(BOOL*)User:(NSString *)user Password:(NSString *)password
```

the code above gives me this error:

```
Conflicting return type in implementation of User:Password: NSArray vs BOOL
```

How do I change this method into a bool ?

Comment: You need to change it (to `BOOL`, no `*`) in both the interface and the implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature should be

```
-(BOOL)User:(NSString *)user Password:(NSString *)password
```

in both header and source file.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct CheckinUser {
    bool user:YES;
    bool pwd:YES;
};
typedef struct CheckinUser CheckinUser;

-(CheckinUser)User:(NSString *)user Password:(NSString *)password
{
    CheckinUser result;
    result.user = YES;
    result.pwd  = NO;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: The OP wants to return a BOOL